# Uncheck the mark in disabled checkbox in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have list of check boxes, In that i disabled one checkbox i.e.SQL.
 When i click on select all button, all the checkbox getting selected.
 Instead i need to select all checkboxes except the disabled one.
Please find the below snapshots.
[image]

currently its showing as in fig 1. I am expecting like in fig 2.
Please find the code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var checkflag = "false";
function check(field) {
  if (checkflag == "false") {
    for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {

      field[i].checked = true;
    }

    checkflag = "true";
    return "Uncheck All";
  } else {
    for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {

      field[i].checked = false;

    }

    checkflag = "false";
    return "Check All";
  }
}

</script>

<form name=myform action="" method=post>
<table>
  <tr><td>
    <strong>Make a selection</strong><br>
    <input type=checkbox name=list value="1">Java<br>
    <input type=checkbox name=list value="2">JavaScript<br>
    <input type=checkbox name=list value="3">ASP<br>
    <input type=checkbox name=list value="4">HTML<br>
    <input type=checkbox name=list value="5" disabled="true" >SQL<br>
    <br>                                                    
    <input type=button value="Check All" onClick="this.value=check(this.form.list)"> 
  </td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/durem/2/edit)**

This is all you need

```
function check(field) {
  var io = field.io ^= 1; // Toggle flag
  for (i=0; i<field.length; i++)
      if(!field[i].disabled) field[i].checked = io;
  return io ? "Uncheck All" : "Check All";
}
```